# How to get around the parameters limit in Linq-to-SQL's .Contains

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a time-consuming Linq-to-SQL query which looks like: `database.GetTable<....>().Where(.....).Join(.......).Join(.......).Join(........).Select(a => new XResult(.......)).ToArray()`. It works quite slow and I tried to speed it up by caching all `XResult` into `static List`.

For that purpose I added `.Where(a => !cachedResults.Contains(a))` into the query sequence, but I faced the problem: `"The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100."`.

So... is it somehow possible to redesign my query in order to get around the parameters limit in SQL? Maybe temporary table? Or somehow redesign the caching mechanism? Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I tried to merge all cached `XResult`s into string and then do `.Where(a => SqlMethods.Like(mergedResults, "%|" + a.Id.ToString() + "|%")).`. It does not crash and maybe it even works, but I could not get the result - I get the SQL timeout. So... it is not the acceptable solution. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you re-write your query as a stored procedure or view in the database and call that from the front-end?

Comment: I can create stored procedure or view but again how will it help me not to pass 20000 of parameters to it?

Comment: One solution would be to pass the parameters as a single parameter - a comma separated string of parameters - to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution.

In database create table-valued function, which receives merged ids as `VARBINARY(MAX)`, splits them and returns table of `INT`s:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIds]
(   
    @data VARBINARY(MAX)
)
RETURNS @result TABLE(Id INT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @data IS NULL
        RETURN 
    DECLARE @ptr INT = 0, @size INT = 4
    WHILE   (@ptr) * @size < LEN(@data)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @result(Id)
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@data, (@ptr* @size) + 1, @size))
        SET @ptr += 1
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Drag it from Server Explorer to DBML designer.

Use it in Linq-to-SQL sequence like any other built-in method, for example I used it as follows: `database.GetTable<....>().Join(database.SplitIds(ConvertIdsToBinary(Ids)), ......).Where(.....).Join(.......).Join(.......).Join(........).Select(a => new XResult(.......)).ToArray()`